# Cannot set read/write for oauth twitter app. Is Twitter's edit app page broken?

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth

Every time I set my twitter app to be read-write is says "settings saved" but the app remains read-only....why? is twitters edit-app page broken??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you are editing your app on https://dev.twitter.com/apps **not** https://twitter.com/apps or https://twitter.com/oauth.